# How to show all users connected to datasnap server?

Tags: delphi

Well, i was taking a look at samples RAD XE2 has with the IDE.
Also on the internet i found :
[Monitoring and Controlling DataSnap TCP/IP Connections](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Monitoring_and_Controlling_DataSnap_TCP/IP_Connections)

My problem is how to access the information about the user: ipaddress username,etc.. which is content in

```
 FConnections.Add(TIdTCPConnection(Event.Connection), Event.Channel);
```

in order to show in the application server a grid or something which connected users.
Well i create a function with a sql query to verify if the user is valid.

```
function UsuarioValido(User,Password :string):boolean;

begin
 server:=TServerMethods1.Create(nil);
  with server.ListaU do
   begin
    Close;
    ParamByName('u').AsString:=User;
    ParamByName('P').AsString:=Password;
    ExecSQL();
    Open;

    if IsEmpty then
  begin
    Result:=false;
  end
  else
  Result:=true;
  end;
end;
```

Then on the userauthenticate event i have:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(
 Sender: TObject; const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string;
var valid: Boolean; UserRoles: TStrings);
begin

valid := UsuarioValido(User, Password);

  if valid then
   begin
    with server.cdslistado do
     begin
      Append;
      server.cdslistadousuario.AsString:=User;
      server.cdslistadoip.AsString:='121';
      Post;

  end;

end;
end;
```

As you can see is a clientdataset in wich i insert the name and the ip of the current connection to show it in a dbgrid. But i can't see changes in dbgrid.

I found other alternative:

```
  TDSSessionManager.Instance.AddSessionEvent(
  procedure(Sender: TObject; const EventType: 
  TDSSessionEventType; const   Session: TDSSession)
  begin
     case EventType of
        SessionCreate:
           SessionInicio(Session); 
        SessionClose:
           SessionFin(Session);  
     end;
  end);
```

Comment: The `TidTCPConnection` has a `Socket` property, which is a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`, which has the IP related information.

Comment: Thanks, probably i need to read the embarcadero's pages about components properties and methods.